# Complex integration in Maple

Tags: integration, maple

The following code takes forever to compute in Maple.  Basically, I'm trying to find the mean-square-modulus of a complex-valued function on a circle centered at the origin.  How should the code be corrected, or is there an online calculator that can achieve this?

```
evalf(subs(subs([n=3, p=1.2451, z=exp(x*I)/2], subs(s=(p/2)*(1+1/(4*z)^n), subs(t=s+sqrt(s^2-1/(4*z)^n), w=z*t^(2/n)))), Int(abs(w)^2, x=0..2*Pi)/(2*Pi)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this any use? I mean does it give the expected result? By supplying the integrand as an operator (black box) the evalf/Int engine is prevented from poking at it too expensively. This can save time, although there is risk involved as it might miss key discontinuities for some problems.

```
> U:=subs(subs([n=3, p=1.2451, z=exp(x*I)/2],
>         subs(s=(p/2)*(1+1/(4*z)^n),
>              subs(t=s+sqrt(s^2-1/(4*z)^n),
>                   w=z*t^(2/n)))),
>         Int(X->eval(abs(w)^2,x=X), 0..2*Pi)/(2*Pi)):

> st:=time():
> evalf(U);
                             0.3351666815

> time()-st;
                                 0.109
```

Another (likely less generally useful possibility) might be,

```
> restart:
> U:=subs(subs([n=3, p=1.2451, z=exp(x*I)/2],
>         subs(s=(p/2)*(1+1/(4*z)^n),
>              subs(t=s+sqrt(s^2-1/(4*z)^n),
>                   w=z*t^(2/n)))),
>         Int(abs(w)^2, x=0..2*Pi)/(2*Pi)):             

> st:=time():
> simplify(U);

                                                -20
                  0.3351666815 - 0.5131390209 10    I

> time()-st;
                                 3.150
```

Comment: Thanks, your first suggestion works.  The second one gives an incorrect result since the integral of a postive function should be positive.

Comment: The second result has the same real part as does the first result. The difference is in a negligible imaginary artifact due to numerical roundoff, which may sensibly be removed using the `fnormal` command. But I gave it as more of a curiosity -- the first way is better, and not just for speed.